# Is there a way to add a tracking generator to a spectrum analyzer?

Tags: function-generator, spectrum-analyzer

As the question suggest, is there a way to add an external tracking generator to a spectrum analyzer which doesnt have a tracking generator? Specifically speaking the HP 8564e spectrum analyzer without the stock tracking generator.

That analyzer seems to have a sweep output bnc connector in the back, which makes me believe that it can somehow control an external signal generator.

So is it possible? if so, which connections are necessary and which type of external generator is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Quick-Start Guide, p. 43

> 12. J8 LO SWP|FAV OUTPUT provides different signals at connector J8: a 0 V to 10 V ramp corresponding to the local oscillator tune ramp, or a
>       sweeping dc output of 0.5 V per GHz of tuned frequency (and 0.25 V for
>       the 8564E/EC and 8565E/EC). The voltage range of the sweeping dc
>       output depends on the spectrum analyzer frequency range. Select the
>       output with the softkeys that are accessed when you press AUX CTRL,
>       REAR PANEL. The 0.25 V/GHz output is needed for frequency ranges above
>       26 GHz. External tracking generators, such as the 85640A, 85644A, or
>       85645A use the 0.5 V/GHz output

Comment: I cant seem to find an output labeled 0.5 V/GHz anywhere on the instrument

Comment: "Select the output with the softkeys"

Comment: @JoeM - How about, like, connector J8, like it says in the quote? Or how about reading the quick start guide, which you can find by Googling?

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to get a similar function to a tracking generator is to use a broadband noise source as the signal fed into the Device Under Test.  Provided the noise source is adequately flat, you will see a very good representation of the pass-band characteristics on the spectrum analyzer.

This noise source doesn't completely replace a proper tracking generator but it is entirely sufficient for checking things like filter or amplifier characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

A tracking generator(TG) is fundamentally simple.

[image: Block Diagram, tracking generator and spectrum analyzer]

A local oscillator and a mixer. Notice that the frequency of the TG is the same as the IF frequency of the spectrum analyzer. That almost is all there is to the likes of an HP8444A* and HP8558B combo. You can not use the DC ramp of the sweep to control a variable LO, the tracking error would be intolerable. At that, now you need a YIG oscillator that matches the the YIG of the spectrum analyzer for the TG LO.

The LO of the TG is slightly adjustable, it doesn't take much. Plug the TG into the spectrum analyzer directly and max the trace out with this adjustment.

From HP:

> When you have selected preselected external mixers, the 0.5 V/GHz
> output provides approximately 1.5 V per GHz of LO frequency, to
> control the preselected mixer

This is what the DC sweep is used for. Well, I got here because I'm thinking of making my own TG. The likes of an Agilent 85640A are almost as pricey as an HP856XE. I don't plan on using it for more than 3Ghz so it should work well enough for the kind of stuff I do. Google *HP 8444A Tracking Generator.pdf* and you will see a nice block diagram.

(*)I'll guess my HP 8444A has been modified for the HP8558B; meaning the ALC should not be functional. I works fine without the third LO input. It is not perfectly flat but accually within a few db across the whole spectrum. For narrow sweeps, does it really matter? For the likes of tuning duplexers, it doesn't.